# Get Oracle Apex item value in Javascript with dynamic action

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am trying to get value of Oracle Apex page item from dynamic action. But i got some error when i am trying to assign it's value to javascript variable. I have tried using :

```
var posisi = $v(‘P1_NAME’);
```

but it keeps me giving "unexpected identifier" error.

Then, i tried using :

```
var posisi=document.getElementById( 'P1_NAME' ).value;
```

it doesn't give any error but, the value is "undefined".
To make sure, I display P1_NAME and it has a value.

any suggestion?

Comment: This may be a bit random.. but why do the single quotes around `P1_NAME` in the top example look weird? I don't think those are single quotes.. it looks like some unicode characters. Is that something you copied and pasted in from somewhere?

Comment: o my gosh, i couldn't notice that in apex , the text is too small to see the difference, but definitely that's the problem. Thanx @jwatts1980 :)